# Falha de segmentação durante conversão de imagem para tons de cinza

Tags: c++, edição-de-imagens

Estou escrevendo código que deve receber um arquivo de imagem em colorido (Formato PPM) e transformá-lo em tons de cinza (formato PGM no código ASC II) Após ter feito funções para ler, converter as cores e salvar o arquivo, o  código está retornando um erro de segmentation fault logo no início da execução do main. Vocês poderiam me ajudar a identificar o erro?
Esse é o código:

```
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# define MAX 500 
typedef struct {
int r, g, b;
} pixel;

void ler_ascii(pixel imagem[MAX][MAX], char *code, int *max, int *coluna, int *linha);
void salvar_ascii(pixel imagem[MAX][MAX], char *code, int max, int coluna, int linha);
void gray_scale(pixel imagem[MAX][MAX], int coluna, int linha);

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {

     pixel imagem[MAX][MAX]; //cria uma matriz de pixeis para armazenar a imagem
     char code[3]; // codigo que identifica se a imagem é ascii ou binÃ¡ria
     int max; //o valor máximo de tonalidade de cada pixel
     int larg, alt; // largura e altura da imagem em pixeis

     ler_ascii(imagem, code, &max, &larg, &alt);
     gray_scale(imagem, larg, alt);
     salvar_ascii(imagem, code, max, larg, alt);

return 0;
} 

void ler_ascii(pixel imagem[MAX][MAX], char *code, int *max, int *coluna, int *linha) {
int i, j;
FILE *arquivo;

char nome_arq[50];
printf("entre com o nome do arquivo: \n");
scanf("%s", nome_arq);

if ((arquivo = fopen(nome_arq, "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo %s\n", nome_arq);
    exit(1);
}

fscanf(arquivo, "%s", code);
fscanf(arquivo, "%d", coluna);
fscanf(arquivo, "%d", linha);
fscanf(arquivo, "%d", max);

for (i = 0; i < *linha; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < *coluna; j++) {
        fscanf(arquivo, "%d", &imagem[i][j].r);
        fscanf(arquivo, "%d", &imagem[i][j].g);
        fscanf(arquivo, "%d", &imagem[i][j].b);
    }
}

fclose(arquivo);
}

void salvar_ascii(pixel imagem[MAX][MAX], char *code, int max, int coluna, int linha) {
int i, j;
FILE *arquivo;

char nome_arq[50];
printf("entre com o nome que deseja salvar: \n");
scanf("%s", nome_arq);

arquivo = fopen(nome_arq, "w");

fprintf(arquivo, "P3\n");
fprintf(arquivo, "%d\n ", coluna);
fprintf(arquivo, "%d\n", linha);
fprintf(arquivo, "%d\n", max);

for (i = 0; i < linha; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < coluna; j++) {
        fprintf(arquivo, "%d ", imagem[i][j].r);
        fprintf(arquivo, "%d ", imagem[i][j].g);
        fprintf(arquivo, "%d\n", imagem[i][j].b);
    }
}

fclose(arquivo);
}

void gray_scale(pixel imagem[MAX][MAX], int coluna, int linha) {
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < linha; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < coluna; j++) {
        imagem[i][j].r = (int) ((0.299 * imagem[i][j].r) + (0.587 * imagem[i][j].g) + (0.144 * imagem[i][j].b)); //calcula o valor para conversão
        imagem[i][j].g = imagem[i][j].r; //copia o valor para
        imagem[i][j].b = imagem[i][j].r; //todas componentes

        //testa o valor para ver se o mesmo não passou de 255
        if (imagem[i][j].r > 255) {
            imagem[i][j].r = 255;
            imagem[i][j].g = 255;
            imagem[i][j].b = 255;

        }

    }
}
}´
```

Obrigado

Comment: Você sabe usar um debugador, como o ddd ou gdb? Ajuda muitissimo a descobrir a causa de falhas de segmentação.

Comment: Em outras palavras, você saberia ao menos indicar mais ou menos a linha onde o erro de segmentação está ocorrendo? O seu código tem algum potencial para falha em alguns lugares. Por exemplo, a leitura do "código" (na linha com `fscanf(arquivo, "%s", code);`) pode produzir invasão de memória se a string de código lida tiver mais do que os 3 bytes alocados na variável `code`.

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando alocar 250.000 pixels (500 * 500) na pilha (que é 3 MB se cada `int` ocupa 4 bytes), e depois você passa essa matriz enorme para outras funções. Acredito que isso estoura a pilha, então a solução é alocar a matriz de pixels *dinamicamente*, pois assim a pilha só guarda um apontador.

Troque:

```
void ler_ascii(pixel imagem[MAX][MAX], char *code, int *max, int *coluna, int *linha);
void salvar_ascii(pixel imagem[MAX][MAX], char *code, int max, int coluna, int linha);
void gray_scale(pixel imagem[MAX][MAX], int coluna, int linha);
```

por:

```
void ler_ascii(pixel **imagem, char *code, int *max, int *coluna, int *linha);
void salvar_ascii(pixel **imagem, char *code, int max, int coluna, int linha);
void gray_scale(pixel **imagem, int coluna, int linha);
```

Atualize as definições das funções para que sejam compatíveis com os novos protótipos mostrados acima.

Assim, em vez de as funções receberem a matriz inteira, elas recebem apenas o apontador para a primeira coluna da primeira linha da matriz. Com isso a pilha não estoura.

Troque (na função main):

```
pixel imagem[MAX][MAX]; //cria uma matriz de pixeis para armazenar a imagem
```

por:

```
pixel **imagem = (pixel**)malloc(MAX * sizeof(pixel*));
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
     imagem[i] = (pixel*)malloc(MAX * sizeof(pixel));
```

Assim, você aloca um arranjo de apontadores, em que cada posição desse arranjo é um arranjo de `pixel`s.

Como você simplesmente usa a matriz em 3 funções seguidas e depois o programa termina, não há muita necessidade de liberar o espaço que foi alocado para a imagem, mas é boa prática fazer isso mesmo assim, pois mais tarde você pode querer acrescentar mais funcionalidade ao seu programa e nesse caso pode surgir a necessidade de liberar a memória alocada, então é bom que o código que libera a memória já esteja presente.

Acrescente isso logo depois de chamar `salvar_ascii` e antes do `return 0;`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
     free(imagem[i]);
 free(imagem);
```

Assim, cada arranjo de `pixel`s em `imagem` é liberado e depois o arrranjo `imagem` é liberado.

Após realizar essas mudanças, o programa deve funcionar.

Comment: Vetores não são copiados na passagem por parâmetro.